# Smooth function on product manifolds

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

suppose $M, N$ are smooth manifolds and $f:M\times N\rightarrow \mathbb{ R }$ is a function such that $\forall y\in N$ the function $x\mapsto f (x, y)$ is smooth and $\forall x\in M$ the function $y\mapsto f (x, y)$ is smooth as well. Does this imply that $f$ is smooth jointly in x and y? The map should be differentiable as far as I know. But I can not see if the map is also differentiable of higher orders.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function need not even be continuous.  For instance, take $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ and define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.  Then $f$ is infinitely differentiable in each variable separately: this is clear at any point besides $(0,0)$, and at $(0,0)$, if you fix either variable to be $0$, then $f$ is identically $0$.  But $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$, since as you approach it along the line $y=x$, $f(x,y)$ is always $1/2$.